# How SQLDataAdapter Fill method fires Database Queries?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sqldataadapter

I have a query in understanding the SQLDataAdapter fill method,which takes arguments like startRecord,MaxRecord as shown below -

```
SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter ("Select * from tblname",ConnectionString);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adap.Fill(ds, startIndex, MaxRecords , "TableName");
```

I want to know what will the SqlDataAdapter do.

Will it first fire the query that would bring back entire record from the table and then filer the rows from it ?

or

Will it fire a query in the database that would select only the required amount of rows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, currentIndex, pageSize, "TableName");` will query for the whole result set and then page them in memory.

For large result sets this is not what you want. If you want the paging to happen on the server use the SKIP and TOP clause in the SQL you use.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx1c9c2f%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is the documentation which explains this.

Answer (score 0):

SqlDataAdapter serves as a bridge with DataSet and SQL Server for retrieving and saving data.
When the SqlDataAdapter fills a DataSet, it will create the necessary tables and columns for the returned data if they do not already exist.

This is segment of code to make you understand better

```
string sqlStatement = "Select * from tblname ";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                adap.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: So,what query will the sqladapter will be firing ?

Comment: sqladapter is a set of command and connection that are used to fill the dataset...

Comment: So,what query will the sqladapter will be firing ? Will it fire the query that would bring entire row data or will it fire a query that would get only selected rows?

Comment: It will dataset based on the sqlstatement. For instance if your sqlstatement return 10 rows then sqladapter will fill the 10 rows in the dataset.

Comment: ok,if my select query return 1000 rows and if i have put a filter in the query (using SqlAdpater fill method) with limit and offset,of say suppose 10 rows.What will be the query that would be fired ?

Comment: DataSet is filled with only 10 record but entire tblname is returned. Use primary key column to identify the next pagesize. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx1c9c2f%28v=VS.100%29.aspx